# How would I go about calculating the number of simultaneous calls of my python script my hardware can handle?

Tags: python, memory, cpu-usage

inb4: I know there are questions out there that address parts of this one individually, but looking for an end-to-end, integrated answer.

So I have a python script which takes a video and uses opencv to do object tracking on it. It takes about 5~10 seconds on my laptop. I want to deploy it to a production server and allow my users to access it. Here are some questions I have:

1) Which hardware parameters I should be thinking about. Right now I'm thinking CPU and memory.

2) Best way to "profile" (I think that's what it's called) my python script to see how much resources it takes to run it once.

3) How to use the answer to (2) to figure out what happens if I run 10 of my python script at once. Or the inverse, if I have xyz hardware, how many of my python script can I run?

4) Considering these questions in terms of both levels: "Will it kill my computer?", and "Will it be painfully slow?".

Happy get any answers here, but I'm particularly looking for something super lean and pragmatic, rather than the absolute best way to do it. **Think if you had 2 hours to figure out what setup you need to go live, how would you do it.**

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Well, that's mainly it. CPU usage and memory consumption, you could make a test script that calculates the avg, max and min usage based on a multicore and maybe multiGPU computer.

2) After that, to profile i like to use profiling library
which can be installed from here
https://pypi.org/project/profiling/
or with `pip install profiling` which for me is the correct minimalistic approach.
You can't use regular C/C++ profilers because python is not compiled.
The answer to 3),4) would be just doing some math around the computer data collected but maybe there could be other better solution. With a multithreading program this could be a nightmare.
If you gather the speed of the core/s of your computer you could translate that into another computer with at least a minimum of ram (So it doesn't bottleneck).
You could use https://pypi.org/project/psutil/ for this matter.